# macros for copy paste command for various sheet of the same excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a new for excel, I have created excel spreadsheet with about 50 sheets with different names. I want to copy cell `a5:a10` to all the sheets at cell `b15:b20`.

I also want to delete cells `a25:a35` from each sheet

at present I have written like this, but it is too much lengthy to include all the sheets. Is there any other short cut method which can copy and paste to all sheets..?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("a5:a10").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("b10:b20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

The name of the sheets : sheet1, sheet2,sheet3....like that upto sheet50

Answer (score 0):

Next code copies range `a5:a10` from sheet1 to another sheets in `b15:b20` and also deletes range `a25:a35` from each sheet:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            ws.Range("b15:b20").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a5:a10").Value
        End If

        'ws.Range("a25:a35").ClearContents
        ws.Range("a25:a35").Delete xlShiftUp
    Next

End Sub
```

if you want just clear content in `a25:a35`, remove line `ws.Range("a25:a35").Delete xlShiftUp` and uncomment line `'ws.Range("a25:a35").ClearContents`